# ApiVersions missing in updated Cert-manager. Cert-manager Conversion webhook for cert-manager.io/v1alpha2, Kind=ClusterIssuer failed

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks, cert-manager

When I am trying to get cluster issuers in my k8s cluster, I am receiving this error message. Can someone help me troubleshoot this?

```
kubectl get cluster issuers 

Output: Error from server: conversion webhook for cert-manager.io/v1alpha2, Kind=ClusterIssuer failed: an error on the server ("") has prevented the request from succeeding
```

Here's my clusterissuer.yml file:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-dev-certificate
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    # The ACME server URL
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    # Email address used for ACME registration
    email: my.email@org.co
    # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-dev-certificate
    # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```

Here's the kubernetes version:

```
kubectl version --short

Output: Client Version: v1.23.1
        Server Version: v1.22.12-gke.2300
```

Comment: hope its not due to space between clusterissuer ?  `kubectl get clusterissuer`

Comment: No, its not about the space or syntax. I actually resolved this issue in whole and will update a response to this question myself.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I thought the problem was when I was trying to get ClusterIssuer or Certificates in Cert-Manager. But later after more troubleshooting, I found that after Cert-Manager 1.5.5, we cannot directly update to Cert-Manager 1.9.1 since some CRD resource gets missed out in between hence causing issue in getting resources like Certificates, ClusterIssuer which are defined as CRDs in Cert-Manager package.

Solution: I downgraded my cert-manager back to 1.5.5 then followed the steps from Cert-Manager's blog on making CRDs ready for Cert-Manager update. Then, updated Cert-Manager back to 1.9.1. And everything was working fine. Here're the steps that I followed:

1. Downgrade back to Cert-Manager 1.5.5:

```
     kaf https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.5.5/cert-manager.yaml
```

2. Install **cmctl** for cert-manager:

```
    curl -sSL -o cmctl.tar.gz https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.9.1/cmctl-linux-amd64.tar.gz
    tar xzf cmctl.tar.gz
    mv cmctl /usr/local/bin
    cmctl upgrade --help
```

3. Upgrade api-versions before cert-manager updates:

```
    cmctl upgrade migrate-api-version
```

Now, its safe to upgrade cert-manager to 1.7.1
4. Upgrade to Cert-Manager 1.7.1 or 1.9.1:

```
    kaf https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.7.2/cert-manager.yaml
    kaf https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.7.2/cert-manager.yaml
```

5. Verify by fetching the CRD resources:

```
    kubectl get clusterissuer
    kubectl get certificates
```